# How do I check to see if a specific string is inside a specific column of multiple dataframes, to then count the number of appearances?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate through a specific column that is titled the same in 4 different dataframes ('Question'), to see if a given word is in each cell, which are all strings. How do I create a function that adds up the number of times a string is found in a list of strings, from different columns?

This is what I have tried so far, but it keeps telling me

> local variable ... defined in enclosing scope on line ## referenced before assignment local variable ... is assigned to but never used

```
word_count_1980 = 0
word_count_1990 = 0
word_count_2000 = 0
word_count_2010 = 0

word = 'computer'

def decade_word_filter(word):
   for question in the_1980s['Question']:
       if word.lower() in question.lower():
            word_count_1980 += 1
   for question in the_1990s['Question']:
       if word.lower() in the_1990s['Question'].lower():
            word_count_1990 += 1
   for question in the_2000s['Question']:
       if word.lower() in the_2000s['Question'].lower():
            word_count_2000 += 1
   for question in the_2010s['Question']:
       if word.lower() in the_2010s['Question'].lower():
            word_count_2010 += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def decade_word_filter(df, word, col='Question'):
   return df[col].str.contains(word).sum()

dfs = [the_1980s, the_1990s, the_2000s, the_2010s]
word_counts = [decade_word_filter(df, word) for df in dfs]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.